# How to build a data widget the angular way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, widget

I have a widget which comprises of a side bar and the content area. The sidebar has a tree component with several tree items. When a tree item is clicked,it fetches its own data and injects the data into the content div.

[image: data widget]

I am using `ajax get` to fetch the data from the server and inserting into the content.

While going through angular,i found this method `http` which makes http requests to a specified server.

In my data widget,i am using jquery and html5 and no angular.The widget works but i am curious how angular js would have approached the building of the same widget.

What are some concepts from angular js that i could have used to come up with the same widget?.

Comment: [Creating Extensible Widgets Part 1: jQuery to AngularJS in 30 seconds](https://blog.thousandeyes.com/creating-extensible-widgets-part-1-jquery-to-angularjs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a real basic concept of how I would create a widget:

The widget would be composed of `controller`, `service`, and template:

**Controller**

- handles click events
- triggers updates in the UI

**Service**

- makes the actual REST calls to retrieve the data

the tree/tabs on the sidebar of your app would be linked to click events in the controller:

**markup**

```
<a ng-click="getContent(tabNumber)">tab label</a>
```

and here's where you display the tab content:

```
<div class="content-area">{{ contentArea }}</div>
```

**controller**

this function gets executed on click from the view:

```
...
$scope.getContent = function(tab) {
  TabService.getContent(tab)
  .then(function(response) {
    // update the view
    $scope.contentArea = response.data.content;
  });
}
```

**service**

the service is then called from the controller's function:

```
app.service('TabService', function($http) {
  return {
    getContent: function(tab) {
      return $http.get(....);
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a real basic working example of those pieces:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tr5OIdwh1QLqOJFfr3xZ?p=preview